# Segue without StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to do an app that will have a Home Button on each View, but I'm looking for a way to navigate to Home Screen on click this button, without make a "physical" link for each screen on StoryBoard to home screen.

I'm try to use this code:

```
@IBAction func btnGoInicio(_ sender: Any) {
    let page = MainVC()
    present(page, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But this crash on a black screen, some one know how I can do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use an unwind segue; they make it easy to get back to a particular view controller no matter how deep your navigation path is.

Comment: Can we assume that all ViewControllers have the HomeScreen as a previous view controller (even if not immediately previous?)

Comment: How come you do not want to use a physical link then use a perform segue action when clicked? seems the easiest way to me

Comment: is there a nav bar to put home button in?  sucks to put a IBAction in every single view controller.  If it must be in view controllers view and not nav bar, I guess you could subclass and define action within button, fire a notification that app delegate gets and wipes out nav stack and inserts home vc at root...thats ugly though

Comment: @JulianSilvestri, 
when the application is ready, I will have more than 30 screens, with several links between them, and if I put these links, it will be impossible to identify the navigation

Comment: See post here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216582/create-and-perform-segue-without-storyboards .   Basically not a good idea to achieve segue without storyboard. The storyboard is an integral part of that process

Comment: Essential you DO need to instantiate your view controller to achieve the desired result. However this is probably not possible for you so again you need to use the storyboard

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 using unwind segue like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULd2v4mHyQ4 solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to instantiate a viewController from storyboard, this way:

```
@IBAction func btnGoInicio(_ sender: Any) {

     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // If you have other storyboard instead of Main, use it

     if let page=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YOU_IDENTIFIER") as! MainVC{ 
//You MUST SET THE VIEW CONTROLLER IDENTIFIER "YOU_IDENTIFIER" FROM INSPECTOR INTO STORYBOARD
        self.present(page, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this method when using segues in your code

```
func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
           sender: Any?)
```

Make sure you set up your segues with identifiers in the storyboard so they can be called later, in the identifiers parameter.

Comment: This is one of the easiest way if you want to call it at a certain point but no button is pressed

Comment: This TN could be useful: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2298/_index.html