# Why I am not successfull to use segue programmatically?

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

I am using storyboard for ScreenOne, and I did not use the storyboard for ScreenTwo, I was coding as programmatically and  until now no problem for me, but I am  still not success to declare
"storyboardIdentifier" for ScreenTwo.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40612138/10991969) there is an example but I don't understand how I will handle this example inside of the app. Any idea will be appreciated.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**ScreenTwo:**

```
class ForgotPasswordEmailCheckController: UIViewController {
  var storyboardId: String {
    return (value(forKey: "ForgotPasswordEmailCheckController") as? String)!
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segue without StoryBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524596/segue-without-storyboard)

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, I was try it also, but did not solved. I know many similar question but they are help to solve

Comment: please share code where u are initializing screenTwo programatically

Comment: @abh, hold on pls I will update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is programmatically way to do it:

in sceneDelegate set your initial navigation controller:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyController())
    window?.rootViewController = controller
}
```

now configure your navigationBar in firstController, use my extension to do it:

```
extension UIViewController {

func configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: UIColor, backgoundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor, title: String, preferredLargeTitle: Bool) {
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgoundColor
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = preferredLargeTitle
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationItem.title = title
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgoundColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationItem.title = title
    }
  }
}
```

This is your first controller looks like:

```
class MyController: UIViewController {

let button = UIButton() // declare your button

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .white, backgoundColor: .black, tintColor: .white, title: "My Vc", preferredLargeTitle: true) // set nav bar with exetnsion
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
        
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 9
    button.setTitle("My Button", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector (handelGoToSecondVc), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    
}
    
@objc func handelGoToSecondVc() {
    let controller = SecondController()
    controller.title = "second Vc"
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
 }
}
```

second controller:

```
class SecondController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .green
 }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Complete code:

```
import UIKit

class MyController: UIViewController {

let button = UIButton() // declare your button

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .white, backgoundColor: .black, tintColor: .white, title: "My Vc", preferredLargeTitle: true) // set nav bar with exetnsion
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
        
    view.addSubview(button)
    button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 9
    button.setTitle("My Button", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector (handelGoToSecondVc), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    
}
    
@objc func handelGoToSecondVc() {
    let controller = SecondController()
    controller.title = "second Vc"
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
 }
}

class SecondController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .green
 }
}

extension UIViewController {

func configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: UIColor, backgoundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor, title: String, preferredLargeTitle: Bool) {
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgoundColor
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = preferredLargeTitle
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationItem.title = title
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgoundColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationItem.title = title
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tnx so much, where I will use extension UIViewController {}...?

Comment: @Skysoft13 copy and paste it below of your controller class... I update my answer with complete code.

Comment: it is work like that tnx so much, but if you look at question, my ViewController not programatically, I have storyboard and SecondView controller wrote programatically.  if you look at other answer it is according to my question but it is not working, is it possible we apply like it?

Comment: @Skysoft13 For sure! configure nav bar using my extension, set the start nav controller in sceneDelegate (simply substitute the name of controller, es.: remove MyController() and paste in ViewController() ), delete my button declaration, and its settings and constraints in viewDidLoad and use your IBOutlet and its settings and constraints, set button target like my code... If you want my advice, do it programmatically, you will have total control of your objects in the scene...

Comment: I want to use @IBOutlet for button, button but How I will handle "@objc func handelGoToSecondVc() {
    let controller = SecondController()
    controller.title = "second Vc"
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
 }
}" for btn, yes ı AGREE with u the best way programmatically, but for this project I have to use storyboard, that is way :)

Comment: @Skysoft13 You must create a IBOutlet action and copy in all handelGoToSecondVc func body:  let controller = SecondController()
        controller.title = "second Vc"
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

Comment: I update like that "  @IBAction func btnn(_ sender: Any) {
        
        func handelGoToSecondVc() {
   let controller = SecondController()
   controller.title = "second Vc"
   navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
    }"  it is build but throw this error " Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MyApp.ViewController: 0x7f940d108de0>."

Comment: No, did you link the function to the button? If you do it: @IBAction func btnn(_ sender: Any) { let controller = SecondController()
        controller.title = "second Vc"
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)} For more I need to see your project, my answer is for programmatically do it...

Comment: I update like that "  @IBAction func butto(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let controller = SecondController()
          controller.title = "second Vc"
          navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    }" still throw like that error " Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MyApp.ViewController: 0x7fb2191072c0>." I am just see black screen green  top navigation bar

Comment: @Skysoft13 I put in Mega a example project for you... https://mega.nz/folder/Bh8GAJyB#023RHIs-3A60FG_KByxyHw

Comment: tnx so so so much, I appreciated ur great help, tnx so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard Controller (Also Embed this controller in Navigation Controller):

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btn.addAction(UIAction(handler: { action in
            
            let secondVC = SecVC()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        }), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Second Viewcontroller:

```
class SecVC: UIViewController {
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try , tnx :)

Comment: btn? where did u declared?

Comment: In your first view controller. don't forget to embed it in the navigation controller or it won't navigate.

Comment: so sorry I didnt get it very well, is it possible u update ur answer? I declared btn.addAction... inside of the SecVC, but how I will declare btn, in where ?

Comment: it is running but when I click the btn it throw error as "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SegueApp.ViewController btn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f819ce08690'"

Comment: Is there any segue attached to it for some other VC. If it's for learning put it on git.

Comment: yes sure I was check but still says "Thread 1: "-[SegueApp.ViewController btn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7fc0607260""

Comment: now not crash, but when I click btn not open SecondView, no action

Comment: Have you embedded the viewcontroller in Navigation Controller?

Comment: @How , can U expain a bit

Comment: Select the controller on the Storyboard, then Click on Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Comment: Did you debug it? is 'pushViewController' getting called?

Comment: it is running but not and motion. here it is "  btn.addAction(UIAction(handler: { action in
               
               let secondVC = SecondView()
               self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
           }), for: .touchUpInside)"

Comment: It should work now. Can't tell what went wrong, add the repo to git then.

Comment: Yes it run,  but I dont know where I miss:) tnx so much for ur great help,  I will add github and share here:)