# prepare for segue programmatically with error: no segue with identifier '<value>''

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on my first iOS project without a storyboard, and I'm running into this issue while trying to segue to another View Controller. Would really appreciate help to understand why this issue is occurring. Do I need to define the segue somewhere? Thank you!

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
>   () has no segue with identifier
>   'goToYViewController''

This is what I have:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToYViewController") {
        if let yInfo = segue.destination as? YViewController {
            yInfo.row = "hello"
        }
    }
}

// in data source

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToYViewController", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: “without a storyboard“ if there is no storyboard, there are no segues, and so none of your code makes any sense.

Comment: [Create and perform segue without storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216582/create-and-perform-segue-without-storyboards)

Comment: see this for help : [Swift programmatically navigate to another view controller/scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39450124/swift-programmatically-navigate-to-another-view-controller-scene/39450328)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using the `storyboard`, you must *push/present* the `YViewController` instance programatically like so,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let yInfo = YViewController()
    yInfo.row = "hello"
    self.present(yInfo, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In the above code, `yInfo` is being *presented*. In case you want to *push* `yInfo` in *navigation stack* use `pushViewController(_:animated:)`,

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yInfo, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't use segue here if you don't have a storyboard. You can either use push or present in order to show the second view controller if you want to do it programmatically.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let YVC = YViewController()
    self.present(YVC, animated: true)
}
```